# React App project unable to run from a shared drive

Tags: reactjs, react-router

i have created a react app on a network share (the whole project is a network drive) becuase this my team will have access to project and do development. but when i do "npm start" it just hangs and doesn't do anything. is the problem that the network is causing this? or is there some issue with the firewall where the development server won't start on my computer

Comment: Did you find any solutions?

Comment: No solutions yet!!!

Comment: I will probably run the project from a VM in the network and just remote access it from my computer. I haven't done any research but I believe this would be the right way to go about it.